# Logging in to Huggingface

Tags: databricks, huggingface

Does anybody have experience running huggingface transformers on Databricks? I can download datasets, model checkpoints, tokenizers, etc without a problem. However, once I have a model fine-tuned (it is a text classification task) I want to upload it to the huggingface hub I haven't found a way to log in via the Databricks notebook.

I tried

```
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login()
```

but, like when the model is training, the notebook doesn't display HTML. So I tried

```
displayHTML(notebook_login())
```

but this gives me a java null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

For private notebooks:

```
!pip install huggingface-hub==0.14.1
!huggingface-cli login --token hf_yourtokentext
```

For shared notebooks, where you'd like to keep your Huggingface token secret, you can use a [widget](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html) to capture the token:

```
!pip install huggingface-hub==0.14.1
dbutils.widgets.text("huggingface_token", "", "huggingface_token")
```

After the above step, you'll see a text box like this at the top of the notebook:

[image]

Enter your token in the text box.

And then you can run the login command again, but this time using the variable:

```
huggingface_token = dbutils.widgets.get("huggingface_token")
!huggingface-cli login --token $huggingface_token
```

Afterwards, you just clear the text box, and the script stays in-tact.